# SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

Error: ***could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet***

I am working on CRUD using JPA in Spring Boot; and trying to insert data in MySQL table using JSP pages.BUT after submitting the form, Table automatically deletes from MySQL Database....

I have gone through all tutorial by searching the Error. I am following [this example](https://www.jackrutorial.com/2018/05/spring-data-jpa-crud-example-spring-boot-tutorial.html)

**student.java**

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;

@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)

    @Column(name="sname")
    private String sname;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="key1")
    private String key1;
}
```

I expect that data should be enter into the mentioned table.

Comment: Please post full error message with stacktrace ([edit] your question, not in comments)

Comment: That code will not throw the exception from your question's title

Comment: I got the solution that i was not using Unique ID field with Auto_Increment option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you face such type of error, while running Spring Boot + JPA CRUD Example, Just **check once that you have defined ID field using AUTO_INCREMENT option or not.** 
I was having such type of Error because I did not require ID field. BUT Spring Boot Hibernate checks for Unique A_I ID field.

**If you don't require ID field, then use**  and Your problem will be solved.